# Choose Qt Version to use with PySide?

Tags: qt, pyside, windows-7-x64

I've been working on a PySide project using Qt 4.8.5 for awhile. There's a bug with Qt 4.8.5 that I keep running into. After a bit of research, I found that the bug first appeared in Qt 4.8.0, but that it didn't exist in Qt 4.7.4. So I decided to try downgrading.

I went to http://download.qt-project.org/archive/qt/4.7/ and I downloaded and ran `qt-win-opensource-4.7.4-vs2008.exe`.

Afterwards, to check that I had actually downgraded, I tried this:

```
$ python
>>> import PySide.QtCore
>>> print(PySide.QtCore.__version__)
4.8.5
>>> print(PySide.QtCore.qVersion())
4.8.5
```

It appears that PySide is still using Qt 4.8.5 instead of Qt 4.7.4. Does anyone know how PySide determines which version of Qt to use when multiple are installed? I don't want to uninstall Qt 4.8.5, because my project already mostly works with it and I'm not certain that using Qt 4.7.4 will actually work better.

The PySide documentation says that PySide works with Qt versions 4.6, 4.7, and 4.8, so I don't think that should be the issue.

If it's important, I'm using a 64 bit version of Windows 7 and I do have Visual Studio 2008 installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Qt 4.7.4, you need to build PySide against that version.
The version you downloaded is "bounded" to the 4.8 version.

However, you can download the 1.1.1 version of PySide, using Qt 4.7.4, from this link: http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/pyside/

Comment: I'll give that a shot in the morning and approve this answer if it works (or comment if it doesn't.)

Comment: BTW, which is the bug you are referring to?

Answer (score 1):

The Windows PySide distributions are stand alone with all Qt libs and utils embedded so it does not mattter which Qt you have installed in your system. Newest PySide 1.2.1 has Qt 4.8.5 embedded.

Comment: +1: Thank you for that information. I wish I could mark both this answer and Angel's answer as correct; alas, I could not, so I had to choose one, and I unfortunately did not choose yours.